# What is the right way to handle char* strings?

Tags: c++

I have a third party library that is using char* (non-const) as placeholder for string values. What is the right and safe way to assign values to those datatypes? I have the following test benchmark that uses my own timer class to measure execution times:

```
#include "string.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sj/timer_chrono.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sj::timer_chrono sw;

    int iterations = 1e7;

    // first method gives compiler warning:
    // conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
    cout << "creating c-strings unsafe(?) way..." << endl;
    sw.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
        char* str = "teststring";
    }   
    sw.stop();
    cout << sw.elapsed_ns() / (double)iterations << " ns" << endl;

    cout << "creating c-strings safe(?) way..." << endl;
    sw.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
        char* str = new char[strlen("teststr")];
        strcpy(str, "teststring");
    }   
    sw.stop();
    cout << sw.elapsed_ns() / (double)iterations << " ns" << endl;


    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
creating c-strings unsafe(?) way...
1.9164 ns
creating c-strings safe(?) way...
31.7406 ns
```

While the "safe" way get's rid of the compiler warning it makes the code about 15-20 times slower according to this benchmark (1.9 nanoseconds per iteration vs 31.7 nanoseconds per iteration). What is the correct way and what are is so dangerous about that "deprecated" way?

Comment: Who's going to free the memory in the safe case? The 3rd party library is badly designed, to be honest.

Comment: If you're going to copy into a temporary buffer, at least use a `vector<char>`.

Comment: *Aside*: `new char[strlen("teststr")+1]` to avoid writing the NUL char outside the buffer.

Comment: Talking about discrepancy in benchmarking.. `char* str = "teststring";` does nothing but assign the address of this (same) string literal in data segment to `str` repeatedly. You can observe the same if you print `str`. This is probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C++ standard is clear:

An ordinary string literal has type “array of n const char” (section 2.14.5.8 in C++11).

and

The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined (section 2.14.5.12 in C++11).

For a string known at compile time, the safe way of obtaining a `non-const char*` is this

```
char literal[] = "teststring";
```

you can then safely

```
char* ptr = literal;
```

If at compile time you don't know the string but know its length you can use an array:

```
char str[STR_LENGTH + 1];
```

If you don't know the length then you will need to use dynamic allocation. Make sure you deallocate the memory when the strings are no longer needed.

This will work only if the API doesn't take ownership of the `char*` you pass.

If it tries to deallocate the strings internally then it should say so in the documentation and inform you on the proper way to allocate the strings. You will need to match your allocation method with the one used internally by the API.

The

```
char literal[] = "test";
```

will create a local, 5 character array with automatinc storage (meaning the variable will be destroyed when the execution leaves the scope in which the variable is declared) and initialize each character in the array with the characters 't', 'e', 's', 't' and '\0'.

You can later edit these characters: `literal[2] = 'x';`

If you write this:

```
char* str1 = "test";
char* str2 = "test";
```

then, depending on the compiler, `str1` and `str2` may be the *same* value (i.e., point to the same string).

("Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation- defined." in Section 2.14.5.12 of the C++ standard)

It may also be true that they are stored in a read-only section of memory and therefore any attempt to modify the string will result in an exception/crash.

They are also, in reality of the type `const char*` so this line:

char* str = "test";

actually casts away the const-ness on the string, which is why the compiler will issue the warning.

Comment: Very good answer! What is the difference between { char literal[] = "teststring"; } and { char* literal = "teststring"; }? The former doesn't doesn't give any compiler warnings at least. The latter one assigns the string (array of chars) to heap and former one assigns it to stack?

Comment: So { char literal[] = "test"; } assigns the character array locally (in stack). If I do { char* str = literal; } after that it will give the pointer an address to this char array that is located in stack? If that is true then whenever 'literal' goes out of scope 'str' points to a non-defined space in memory?

Comment: @seb Yes. But if `literal` was in scope when you called you API function it will still be in scope when it returns, so `str` will always point to valid memory. The only issue would be if the API stores the `char*` internally, say in a global, and the *pointer* is dereferenced by the API at a later time when `literal` went out of scope. In this case, I would expect the API to let you know about this "feature".

Answer (score 5):

The unsafe way is the way to go for all strings that are known at compile-time.

Your "safe" way leaks memory and is rather horrific.

Normally you'd have a sane C API which accepts `const char *`, so you could use a proper safe way in C++, i.e. `std::string` and its `c_str()` method.

If your C API assumes ownership of the string, your "safe way" has another flaw: you can't mix `new[]` and `free()`, passing memory allocated using the C++ `new[]` operator to a C API which expects to call `free()` on it is not allowed. If the C API doesn't want to call `free()` later on the string, it should be fine to use `new[]` on the C++ side.

Also, this is a strange mixture of C++ and C.

Comment: He can't really use `std::string::c_str()`, because he's saying the API wants a non-const

Comment: If the API is just poorly-written, that's exactly what const_cast is for.

Comment: @SebastianRedl That may create a UB in his program

Comment: @CharlesSalvia D'oh, didn't remember `c_str()` returns `const char *`, although that is of course pretty obvious. Thanks, I edited.

Comment: How come the "unsafe" way don't leak memory? I'm assigning a pointer on every iteration and never deleting it. The "safe" way leaks memory obviously. Good point about new[] and free().

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Instead of using something like `str.data()`/`std.c_str()` and getting a `const char *`, can't seb use `&str[0]` to get a plain `char *`?

Comment: @Pillsy - it's debatable if that's guaranteed to work prior to C++11 requiring string implementations to be contiguous

Comment: @seb your compiler is just assigning the address of the string to a variable. You are not muddling with the heap at all, no memory allocation is taking place. That's why it doesn't leak. It's exactly like `int i = 10;` Your 'safe' way is allocating memory dynamically, your 'unsafe' way is not.

Comment: @seb, `str` is being assigned the same address over and over again. there is just one string literal in data segment and just like global variable it remains until program terminates

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about C strings here.

```
cout << "creating c-strings unsafe(?) way..." << endl;
sw.start();
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
{
    char* str = "teststring";
}
```

Here, you're just assigning a pointer to a string literal constant.  In C and C++, string literals are of type `char[N]`, and you can assign a pointer to a string literal array because of array "decay".  (However, it's deprecated to assign a non-const pointer to a string literal.)

But assigning a pointer to a string literal can't be what you want to do.  Your API expects a non-const string.  String literals are `const`.

> What is the right and safe way to assign values to those [char* strings]?

There's no general answer to this question. Whenever you work with C strings (or pointers in general), you need to deal with the concept of *ownership*.  C++ takes care of this for you automatically with `std::string`.  Internally, `std::string` owns a pointer to a `char*` array, but it manages the memory for you so you don't need to care about it.  But when you use raw C-strings, you DO need to put thought into managing the memory.

How you manage the memory depends on what you're doing with your program.  If you allocate a C-string with `new[]`, then you need to deallocate it with `delete[]`. If you allocate it with `malloc`, then you must deallocate it with `free()`.  A good solution for working with C-strings in C++ is to use a smart pointer which takes ownership of the allocated C string.  (But you'll need to use a `deleter` that deallocates the memory with `delete[]`).  Or you can just use `std::vector<char>`.  As always, don't forget to allocate room for the terminating null char.

Also, the reason your 2nd loop is so much slower is because it allocates memory in each iteration, whereas the 1st loop simply assigns a pointer to a statically-allocated string literal.

Comment: I don't know if the first method is unsafe at all, I just get the compiler warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings] ... Is there a reason to worry about this warning?

Comment: @seb it is deprecated because those strings are actually arrays of `const char` and changing them leads to undefined behavior. see my response.